# What does the expression for(int& item : v4) means :

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, iteration

v4 is a vector, the loop is to iterate through the vector list and display the elements in the vector. what does the expression inside the for loop means.
[the code is as follows :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Qtm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). It iterates over all the elements of the `v4` vector, and lets you process via the `item` variable in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It iterates through the container v4, whatever that is, let's say it's a vector
The & in "int&" means that it's a reference, if you change the item, it's gonna change the value in the as well.
Similar to

```
for (int i = 0; i < v4.size(); i++){
        item = v4[i];
        //...
    }
```

Comment: ok, I understood that. So, what's the benefit in creating an integer reference variable to store the elements of v4?

Comment: If you have a reference you can modify them while iterating. So if you do something like item = newValue, it's gonna change the value of that element in the initial container. If you don't use a reference, just for(auto item: v4) then the item will actually be a copy of the element in the array. This is true for primitive types, for classes & pointers it's more complicated